# YAML error : end of the stream or a document separator is expected

Tags: yaml

I'm getting the following error in a yaml file
****Error : end of the stream or a document separator is expected at line 2, column 11:
apiVersion: v1
^
Line : undefined  undefined****

This is the entire contents of the file

```
<<EOT
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
    - cluster:
    server: https://3F46DDD9022BD149B88DA7ED4AFB2B30.gr7.eu-west-1.eks.amazonaws.com
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUN5RENDQWJDZ0F3SUJBZ0lCQURBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRc0ZBREFWTVJNd0VRWURWUVFERXdwcmRXSmwKY201bGRHVnpNQjR>  name: kubernetes
  contexts:
    - context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: aws
  name: aws
current-context: aws
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: aws
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      args:
        - "token"
        - "-i"
        - "terraform-eks-demo"

EOT
```

---

I've been googling this for hours but I'm getting nowhere tried . I've tried every YAML linter I can find, can anybody point me in the right direction? I am new to this, if that wasn't obvious

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove `<<EOT` and `EOT`. You probably copied them from some code that injected YAML into a command line utility via a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) but they should not part of the YAML content.

What happens is that when the YAML processor sees `<<EOT` (which parses as part of a YAML scalar because `<` is not a special character) and then a new line. A multiline scalar at root level must be the single root node of a document. When the second line is read, the YAML processor sees a `:` which is not allowed here. At this point, both lines have been read as multiline scalar, and a multiline scalar cannot be used as mapping key. Therefore, the processor complains that after the single root node of the YAML document, the document must end, but instead you try to start a mapping.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should keep a space before 'v1' at line2.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I was entering URL in address-bar like this, **localhost:{port}/Swagger/index.html**, but it should be as like as in our launchSettings.json(if is mentioned there) or like **localhost:{port}/swagger**. It resolved my problem.

Thank you.